# htaccess mod rewrite w/ dynamic match

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am moving a blog from one server to another and adding a subdomain, so the path will change from -

```
http://www.example.com/queen/index.php/2009/winners-and-losers/
```

to -

```
http://blogs.example.com/queen/2009/winners-and-losers/
```

What mod_rewrite rules would I add to the .htaccess under `/queen/` on `www.example.com` to 301 redirect to the new `http://blogs.example.com/queen/`?

What is changing is the '`www`' > '`blogs`' and the '`index.php/`' is going away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) http://blogs.example.com/queen/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And if that folder is also accessible through other host names but the rule should only be applied within *www.example.com*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) http://blogs.example.com/queen/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I get a 404 when I try that.  The old .htaccess used to look like this-

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/?)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

I renamed the sub-folder it was in and created a new /queen/ folder that is empty except for the .htaccess file that now has-

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) http://blogs.theroanoker.com/queen/$1 [L,R=301]

But my URLs generate a 404.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Marty: Don’t use `RewriteBase` if you don’t need to alter the base URL path.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

RewriteRule ^.*/index.php(.*)$ http://blog.foo.com/queen$1 [R=301]